# testing 3 port bit values and Anding the values

Tags: pic, port

i am flashing an led, but if i detect that 3 port pins all have 0 on them, Anding the result all to zero, i wish the led to stop flashing. But why doesnt his work?

`if (RB3 & RB4 & RB5 == 0){
        RB6  = RB6;
        }
        else
        RB6  = !RB6;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a C question than an EE question. Consider the operator precedence for comparison (==) which is 7 vs. bitwise AND (&) which is 8.

So you have RB3 & RB4 & (RB5 == 0). So it will be true if RB3 is 1, RB4 is 1 and RB5 is 0, probably not what you wanted.

Maybe (0 == (RB3 | RB4 | RB5))  is what you want.

Note that I prefer to avoid putting an Lvalue on the left side of a comparison expression. That's a style thing- if one of the = signs is omitted (a common error) then the compiler will emit an error message rather than (at best) a warning- since it's otherwise a valid assignment statement.